# how to use command results values in a table in bash shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

when I run most shell commands they give results as tables

ex

```
$lsof -i :8080
COMMAND  PID              USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    7610 treinetic-macbook   50u  IPv6 0x49a7d04a92982f61      0t0  TCP
```

If I want to use one of those results how can i do that in a shell script.

ex- think that i want to use PID value of above result.

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have constraints? How do these two work for you: `kill -9 $(lsof -i :8080 | tail -1 | sed -e 's/  */ /g' | cut -f2 -d' ')` or `myPID=$(lsof -i :8080 | tail -1 | sed -e 's/  */ /g' | cut -f2 -d' '); kill -9 $myPID` ?

Comment: i did,nt .but i will try

Comment: what do you really want? extracting something from a tabular output?

Comment: yes, way to use any of those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can `-t` to have `lsof` only return the PID:

```
 kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :8080)
```